# Determine the scroll position in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, collections, collectionview

I have a collection view, which is scrollable horizontally. It displays a list of elements horizontally.
[This is my collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLtBi.png)

I want to add an element in the middle of the collection view where my scrollbar is currently at.  Let's say I drag the scrollbar all the way to the right, then the added element should be in the middle of the rightmost section. How do I determine the scrollbar position in the collection view?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property on `UICollectionView` (or rather of its based class `UIScrollView` named `contentOffset` - it indicates of how much content is currently moved (scrolled).

Then you need to use this value and combine it with half of `collectionView.frame.size.width` to get a position at which you need to place your new element.

Now once you have that, you need to use `- (nullable UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` and iterate over all elements to find a proper `indexPath` you need to use for new elements.

`NSIndexPath` is required for inserting new elements at the end. Once you have that, you need to add new element to your `dataSource` and reload `UICollectionView`.